# Remove items from a list in Python based on previous items in the same list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Say I have a simple list of numbers, e.g.

```
simple_list = range(100)
```

I would like to shorten this list such that the gaps between the values are greater than or equal to 5 for example, so it should look like

```
[0, 5, 10...]
```

FYI the actual list does not have regular increments but it is ordered

I'm trying to use list comprehension to do it but the below obviously returns an empty list:

```
simple_list2 = [x for x in simple_list if x-simple_list[max(0,x-1)] >= 5]
```

I could do it in a loop by appending to a list if the condition is met but I'm wondering specifically if there is a way to do it using list comprehension?

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a list comprehension?  The answer is likely yes . . . However, I'm guessing it would be a monstrous comprehension.  The loop here will be cleaner (Or possibly using a generator function if appropriate. . .)

Comment: What do you mean by gaps greater than or equal than 5? How do you want to determine the gaps? Are they random?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. By `gap` you mean the different between any two consequent numbers, is that it ? It's not clear in your question

Comment: Please, provide an example with expected output to clarify your question?

Comment: Well really, the best way to do that would be like so `range(0, 100, 5)`. =D

Comment: How do you want to determine it? If you take the first and last items, you'll get a list which is shorter (two elements) and "the gaps between the values are greater than 5", which fits. If you want "the longest possible shorter list", you'll want to do something different than if you want "any possible shorter list". But either way, I think you don't want what you asked for - "based on previous items in the same list", or you will get any element pair which happen to be >5 apart, you want "based on the previous number you added to the new list".

Comment: Just realized this myself. I think there are two checks for possible answers that would be good to have included in the question: If the sought function is called `f` then the expected values are: `f(range(100)) = [0,5,10,15, ...]` and `f([1, 6, 12, 14, 17, 22, 27])=[6, 12, 22, 27]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a use case for a comprehension, you have to use a loop as there could be any amount of elements together that have less than five between them, you cannot just check the next or any n amount of numbers unless you knew the data had some very specific format:

```
simple_list = range(100)

def f(l):
    it = iter(l)
    i =  next(it)
    for ele in it:
        if abs(ele - i) >= 5:
            yield i
            i = ele
    yield i


simple_list[:] = f(simple_list)
print(simple_list)
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95]
```

A better example to use would be:

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10, 12, 13, 13, 18, 24]

l[:] = f(l)

print(l)
```

Which would return:

```
[1, 10, 18, 24]
```

If your data is always in ascending order you can remove the `abs` and just `if ele - i >= 5`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works nicely. In hindsight I shouldn't have given range(100) as the example list as it's a bit confusing. The real list is much more like the [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10, 12, 13, 13, 18, 24] example you gave

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, which I'm not sure I do (please clarify), you can do this easily. Assume that `a` is the list you want to process.

```
[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if abs(a[i] - a[i - 1]) >= 5]
```

This gives all elements with which the difference to the previous one (should it be next?) are greater or equal than 5. There are some variations of this, according to what you need. Should the first element not be compared and excluded? The previous implementation compares it with index -1 and includes it if the criteria is met, this one excludes it from the result:

```
[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if i != 0 and abs(a[i] - a[i - 1]) >= 5]
```

On the other hand, should it always be included? Then use this:

```
[v for i,v in enumerate(a) if (i != 0 and abs(a[i] - a[i - 1]) >= 5) or (i == 0)]
```

Comment: The list on that test is sequencial and all elements have increment o 1 to one another (none of them is greater than five). Notice the author mentioned `FYI the actual list does not have regular increments but it is ordered`, noticeably that the increments are not regular.

Comment: By my understanding, lists that have no increments greater or equal to 5 should return empty lists, so this code is correct

Comment: the OP gave `range(100)` as an example.

Comment: Yes, and then said: the **actual** list does **not** have  regular increments